# Nightwatch.js. Get node children, iterate through them

Tags: nightwatch.js

My task is get children of some element, iterate through them, and using nightwatch assert make some tests. Here is example of code, what I need:

```
browser.url("http://someurl.com")
     .getAttribute("#parent", "children", function (children) {
         var assert = browser.assert;

         var fisrtChild  = children[0];
         var secondChild = children[1];

         assert.equal(fisrtChild.innerHTML, "Hello");
         assert.equal(secondChild.innerHTML, "World");
    })
```

So, is Nightwatch can do something like this?

P.S. I tried to use 'elements' command, but it returns something like this:

```
{ state: 'success',
sessionId: '63af98a9-d395-4e44-9529-e24a7ad7ff87',
hCode: 1223583237,
value: [],
class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
status: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly "children" is NOT a valid attribute for HTML elements.

Secondly the callback function will simply pass the result of said command should you give it an argument. So the object displayed is in actual fact the result of the getAttribute command.

you could probably use the browser.execute command to allow you to do what you are trying to do

Essentially do something like the following: -

```
var firstChild;
var secondChild;

browser.execute(function() {

       var childNodes = [];

       childNodes.push(document.getElementById('parentID').childNodes);
       firstChild = childNodes[0].innerHTML;
       secondChild = childNodes[1].innerHTML;

}, [])
```

You will then be able to perform assertions on the values of `firstChild` and `secondChild`.

NOTE: Have not tested this and you may need to play around with it a little but hopefully you get the general idea

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code. It will fetch all the buttons and then click on all sequentially.

```
browser
  .url("http://someurl.com")
  .elements('css selector', "button", function (links) {
      for (var i = 0; i < links.value.length; i++) {
        browser.elementIdClick(links.value[i].ELEMENT);
      }
   })
```